# Java multithreading method access

Tags: java, multithreading

Can I access the process method in Runner class from a thread's run method even without creating a Runner object ?Why ?

```
class Runner {
  public void process() {
    // some multithreaded code
  }
}

main() {
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    process();
                }
           });
t1.start();        
}
```

Comment: You can't. Any reason why you don't want to create an object of Runner?

Comment: I don't think we "access" methods, and the statement doesn't make sense to me, but rather we access objects.

Comment: What class is `main()` in? Why does it not have parameters? What do you mean by the comment "multithreaded code"?

Comment: if the main() method is inside the class Runner, then yes. But you can't call from outside the class a non-static method without initiating it first.

Answer (score 2):

You can if you make it `static`:

```
class Runner {
      public static void process() {
        // some multithreaded code
      }
    }
```

Then:

```
public static void main() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Runner.process();
                }
           });
    t1.start();        
}
```

But, you won't be able to reference `process()` method without the `Runner.` qualification or without instantiation. This is because `Java` is an `Object Oriented` language.

Answer (score 0):

If Runner's process method was static, you could.

You can't access an Object's non-static methods without instantiation. You just need to perform your due-diligence when making that method thread safe.